# How to programmatically set Permission settings on private MSMQ queue for remote access?

Tags: .net, ironpython, msmq, message-queue

As part of an application I'm developing, Im trying to make use of Microsoft Message Queueing functionality and im having trouble with permission settings.

I want to create a queue and send messages to it on a server computer and access it from a client computer over the local network. Both computers (both Windows 7 Home Premium) are on the same LAN network and are able to ping to each other. I will know the exact path of the created queue, so I guess private queues are ok.

Im basing my code on [this example](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Message_Queuing)  and use IronPython to access the [MessageQueue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.messaging.messagequeue%28v=vs.80%29) from the System.Messaging namespace. The send & receive setup from the example works to create a queue and send it a message in one console:

```
>>> localQueue = MessageQueue.Create('.\\private$\\testQueue')
>>> localQueue.FormatName
'DIRECT=OS:<clientMachineName>\\private$\\testQueue'
>>> localQueue.Send('hello from other console')
```

and then access the queue and peek at it in another console by the following code:

```
>>> SemiRemoteQueue = MessageQueue('FormatName:Direct=OS:<clientMachineName>\\private$\\testQueue')
>>> SemiRemoteQueue.Peek()
<System.Messaging.Message object at 0x000000000000002F [System.Messaging.Message
]>
```

When I create a new queue on the server computer, I seem to be able to establish a connection from the client computer, but fail to get any message data from it. Peeking from client to queue created at server, gives the following 'Access denied' error message:

```
>>> ReallyRemoteQueue = MessageQueue('FormatName:Direct=OS:<serverMachineName>\\private$\\remoteTestQueue')
>>> ReallyRemoteQueue.Peek()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EnvironmentError: System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Access to
 Message Queuing system is denied.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int3
2 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback rece
iveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 actio
n, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction in
ternalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Peek()
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
 frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T
1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke0Instruction.Run(InterpretedF
rame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 a
rg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Hosting.PythonCommandLine.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RunOneInteraction
>b__0()
```

I've found that accessing remote private MSMQ queues should be possible, but can't figure out how to set the right permissions. I have allowed MSMQ in Firewall settings and even tried with firewall turned off. Found some discussion about applying permission settings to queue files but this doesn't help as I dont have queue files that have the security settings working for them. I haven't gotten round trying the option of given full access to 'Anonymous Logon' as has been suggested, but would eventually like to set permissions programmatically (in code), not in files' context menus. Should I use the SetPermissions method in the MessageQueing Class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd48yz36(v=vs.80))? How do I specify its parameters?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

> localQueue.SetPermissions("Everyone",
>   MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlEntryType.Allow);

"Everyone" could be any domain account e.g "Domain\MyUserName"

Answer (score 1):

You will need in the first instance to give the 'Anonymous Logon' the rights to receive messages from the queue.

I use this (C#) code for setting permissions which I found [here](http://konste.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/beyond-messagequeue-security-how-to-take-ownership-of-msmq-queue/):

```
AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
Trustee owner = new Trustee(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, Environment.MachineName, TrusteeType.User);
MessageQueueAccessControlEntry aceOwner = new MessageQueueAccessControlEntry(owner, MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
acl.Add(aceOwner);
messageQueue.SetPermissions(acl);
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I tried:
- Changing individual permission settings (queue file->Security->Advanced->Change Permissions->Add) and added both "Everyone" and "Anonymous Logon" with Full Control
- Done the same for containing "lqs" folder
- Followed your recipe; I can set permissions for a Trustee of type User, but when I try the computer name as 1st and second argument to the Trustee constructor, the `SetPermissions()` method cannot resolve it.
I compared the queue file before and after setting Permissions and the security options are identical...
Still get the same error from remote computer.

Comment: Just tried [another of the overloaded setPermission methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x58dfx7z(v=vs.80)) and this does change the security setting in the file. I can specify UserName and ComputerName, but cant get remote ComputerName resolved. How could I specify this? Might Workgroup install be an issue?